# How to get BBedit to auto-continue a block-comment?

Tags: bbedit

I'm used to `vim` adding a  `*`  at the start of each line when typing a block comment in Javascript, C, or Go. I noticed that BBedit doesn't do this. Is there a way to get it to do that? I probably overlooked some setting somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Probably not a valid Stack Overflow question; try Ask Different. Or write to BareBones directly (they're very helpful). But basically no, that's not the kind of thing BBEdit does.  Try TextMate or SublimeText maybe? Or stick with vim! — Man, paper tape, punch cards, even toggling the register bits by hand, I've been there.

Comment: Thanks... I'm trying to settle on one "big" IDE-like editor... had been playing around with TextMate, and thought I'd try + buy BBedit... like you said, maybe I'll just stay with vim. The fingers know what to do there! :-)

Comment: Note too that the `*` is just a piece of decoration; it isn't part of the block comment syntax. So it isn't a normal thing to want.